# Kernel Module keeps getting stuck?

Tags: linux, kernel-module

Every time a pointer points to a null value or something, the module gets stuck and refuses to get removed or unloaded. the only way to get rid of it is to restart the machine. Is there anyway not to have to restart so often? I've already tried to force it to remove by using `rmmod -f` but no use. I'm running kernel v 2.6.35

Comment: Don't dereference null pointers? Write better code with more care?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, once the kernel encounters an exception during execution (i.e. an oops) it may be in an inconsistent state. There's no way to recover from this other than to reboot.

I even think that it's a mistake for the kernel to try to keep running after it encountered an oops. (You can get that behaviour by setting `/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_oops` to 1.)